# Error while creating backup of SQL Azure with Data Tier Application Wizard

Tags: azure-sql-database, backup, data-export

I am trying to create a backup of a SQL Azure database with Data tier application wizard of SQL management Studio but I obtain a lot of errors like the following:

One or more unsopported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package error sql 71501....

Any hint on how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found something on Microsoft techcommunity posted by Azure DB support team which may help you:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/exporting-a-database-that-is-was-used-as-sql-data-sync-metadata/ba-p/369062

You can also consider [Export to a BACPAC file - Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export).